# 2nd event not firing

Tags: javascript, events

please have a look at this simplified code example:

```
myInputElement.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  loader.classList.remove('hide');
  save()
    .then(response => {
      loader.classList.add('hide');
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
});

myButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // do something
});
```

Now, if I type in some text in `myInputElement` and then click on `myButton`, the blur event is fired while the click event is not.
However, if I remove the `loader.classList.remove('hide')` both events are fired.

Can someone explain to me why that is or how I can solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: what is `myInputElement` and `myButton` and `loader`? i.e. a little bit of HTML for context - try to make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Cannot reproduce ~ https://jsfiddle.net/vwodbfzq/ (open the console). If I had to guess, your _"loader"_ pushes the content down when it appears, moving the button and missing the click

Comment: "pushes the content down"
--> that actually helped. loader is a layer that pops up and shows a loading animation that covers the input element and the button. I added a negative z-index  to the layer to see what happens and: Now it works.

Comment: Great, glad you solved it